# Add screen flow action in Einstein bot

Tags: visual-workflow, einstein

I have been trying to add Screen flow action in Einstein bot but unable to add it because it showing 'No Invocable action found'. I have gone through to this below link in which autolaunched flow action is added in bot but did find anything that supports Screen flow action in bot.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_call_flow_action.htm

Here is attached screen flow attachments

[image: Screen Flow]

[image: Screen flow on home page]

[image: Can't access Screen flow in Bot Builder]

Comment: Hi kunal, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Without knowing *specificaly* what you have tried and what errors are preventing you from accomplishing your task, it will be very difficult for the community to help you. We are not mind readers. Please **[edit]** your post to clearly indicate what you have tried, and if you get any errors, please also include the message(s) *verbatim*.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have updated the question along with an attachment for this  issue. Please look into it and let me know if you have a suggestion regarding it

Answer (score 1):

After enable Run Flows permission in Bot Set Permission, you have to activate flow in the flow list ( not debug or run ). Simply click activate next to flow you want to have in your dialog in Bot Builder.